# All WF 2010 suddenly fail on start

Tags: 2010, workflow, error, 2016

We have a SP 2016 Farm, migrated from 2013 which has been migrated from 2010 and have many workflows (2010 and 2013). All worked fine up to yeaterday morning, where suddenly every workflow 2010 stuck on `starting` and in the workflow history many entries with `falied to run` and `falied to start`:

[image]

I struggled into the ULS-Viewer...did not find any error. I guess the problem is related to the Timer Job and/or to the last CU (September 2017), it has been installed a few days ago. Looking for help!

Workflows 2013 run fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check on the SQL instance log whether there is any permissions that are denied. Likely for Farm account. CU application can revoke dbo permissions.

Comment: If it were a db permission problem, I think it would rise a 401 Exception or something similar.